# CSS table width: something missing?

Tags: css

I am facing a issue with CSS3: on my site, I have a `<DIV>` which contains a table with single row and two columns

I have set width in percent (CSS) but facing an issue.

In my screen resolution, it is placed perfectly but for screens with larger size, it get to left size but I want it to be in centre.

This is live on http://www.dbadvices.com/ just below Menu (where there is a Follow Us thing).

Comment: I hope I made my question clear enough!
I am talking about <div id="dbtab"> thing on page!

Comment: add id to table id="myTable", and then add css for that #myTable td 
{
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}

Comment: @Piyush : Added that, but still its the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<table style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
   <tbody><tr>
   <td id="fbfollow" width="33%"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dbadvices"><img    src="http://www.dbadvices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FollowUs.png" alt="Follow us on  Facebook"></a></td>
    <td id="adfollow" width="65%"><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
     <!-- DBAdvices -->
     <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0588760936983970" data-ad-slot="5129604783"></ins>
  </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Always remeber to align a table in center use this

```
margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;
```

Works in all resolution.